# jquery+ springboot, CORS issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-boot, cors

My front end pages are developed whit jquery 3.2.1, running by npm like this

```
"start": "http-server -a localhost -p 8000 -P http://localhost:8080 -c-1 --cors ./app"
```

my http request example:

```
$(function(){

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/partner/all',
            type:'get',
            dataType:'text',
            success:function(data){
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    }
)
```

and I get the cors error, like this

No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

then I add the filter for cors supports

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
```

now only one error is:

GET http://localhost:8080/api/partner/all 403 ()

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score -1):

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` and `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` are incompatible.

If you **need** to pass `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` (because you require cookie/authentication support) you will have to specify `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {value-of-Origin-request-header}` (in your example, you could hardcode it to be `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8000`).

Comment: Huh - why the downvote? Your code as-is will not work, because of the incompatibility between two of your CORS response headers. This might be causing the problem...